# Product topology on the set $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

I want to define a product topology on the set $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Actually, I have three options to define a topology on $\{0,1\}$ (trivial topology, {{},{0}or{1},{0,1}, discrete topology).

I know that product of discrete topologies is not a product topology (it is the box topology).

**My idea:** I think product topology on  $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ must be define with the trivial topologies on $\{0,1\}$ but I could not show it is  the product topology. Any idea or comment will be good for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For every topology on $\{0,1\}$ you can define both a product topology, and a box topology.

Comment: How can I define a product topology on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ ? @Mark

Comment: Do you know how the product topology is defined?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a basis of a product topology?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon "note that if $\{0\}$ is open then so is $\{1\}$", this is not true. It is perfectly fine to take $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0, 1\}\}$ as a topology on $\{0, 1\}$. This is known as the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). So there are four possible topologies (3 up to homeomorphism).

Comment: @MarkKamsma Oh dear, I forgot that open sets aren't closed under complements! That was my confusion. I knew that $\{1\}$ was the complement of $\{0\}$ : but this designates it as a closed set rather than open. Then you are correct, I see four topologies with the two three-set topologies being homeomorphic.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Happens! I'll leave my comment up, because it contains possibly useful information about the topologies involved in the question.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Your comment is certainly useful! Do leave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, up to isomorphism you have three topologies on $\{0,1\}$ you could use: discrete, indiscrete (aka trivial) and the Sierpiński topology (with one open singleton as non-trivial open sets). Whichever you pick, you can always form the product topology and the box topology on the infinite power $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$. If $\{0,1\}$ is given the discrete topology, then the *box* product will also be discrete and therefore not very interesting. In general the usual topology, the default one, on powers such as these is the product topology, which has the best properties: in this case the power is always compact (as a product of compact spaces, as $\{0,1\}$ in *any* topology is compact, being finite). In the case where we choose the topology on $\{0,1\}$ to be connected, the product will also be (this holds true for both the Sierpiński and indiscrete topology).

We usually take the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$ (it's the order topology and the unique metrisable, or even Hausdorff, one) and the product topology. We then get that $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor middle third set and is a compact topological group; it has many good properties: it's up to homeomorphism the only compact metrisable space that has no isolated points and no non-trivial connected subsets.